# prove that quadrangle is isosceles trapezoid

Tags: geometry

How to prove that quadrangle $ABCD$ is a isosceles trapezoid? 
where $AB$ is parallel to $CD$

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: I am little confused here. I see 4 points on a circle forming a quadrilateral of which opposite angles add to 180° All vertices are connected with center O. If I draw 4 random points on a circle and make a quadrilateral out of it, what is so isosceles about it?

Comment: @imranfat: Note that $AB$ and $CD$ have been specified to be parallel.

Comment: Ah, didn't catch that

Answer (score 1):

$AB$ is parallel to $CD$ and then, $\angle BCD=\angle BAD=\angle ADC$. thus, $BD=AC$

Answer (score 0):

Well, since $AB$ is parallel to $CD,$ then you already know it is a trapezoid. Note that the segments drawn to the center $O$ from the vertices of the trapezoid split it into isosceles triangles. If you can show that $\angle AOC$ and $\angle BOD$ have the same measure, it will follow that $AC$ and $BD$ are of the same length, as desired.

Comment: could you give me a hint how to prove that $\angle AOC$ and $\angle BOD$ are equal?

Comment: Try dropping a perpendicular bisector from $AB$ through $O$ to $CD$, and see what you can come up with when you mark the congruent angles that result.

Comment: are you sure? I don't see any congruent angles :(

Comment: Note that since $O$ is the center of the circle, then for example, $AOB$ is an isosceles triangle, so a perpendicular bisector of $AB$ passes through $O$, and in fact bisects $\angle AOB$. We can do something similar with $COD$, using the aforementioned perpendicular bisector.

Answer (score 0):

You are given two facts:

```
    1. A qualrilateral ABCD is inscribed in a circle.
    2. AB is parallel to CD
```

Because of the parallel lines, qualrilateral ABCD is, by definition, a trapezoid.

To prove that trapezoid ABCD is isosceles, you need to show that the non-parallel sides BD and AC have equal lengths.  This can be accomplished as follows.  Erase the lines that go to the circle's center. Draw a single line from point A to point C.  Finish the proof by using these three theorems:

```
    1. If parallel lines are cut by a transversal, 
       then the alternate interior angles measure the same.

    2. In a circle, the arc subtended by an inscribed angle has
       twice the measure of the inscribed angle.

    3, In a circle, if two minor arcs are equal in measure, 
       then their corresponding chords are equal in length.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two given facts:inscribed quadrilateral and AB is parallel to DC
From 1st given fact,
We can know that the sum of opposite angles of inscribed quadrilateral is 180.
angle DAB +angle BCD = 180
From 2nd,
Since AB is parallel to DC,
angle ABC + angle BCD = 180
So, we get angle DAB + angle BCD = angle ABC + angle BCD
        Therefore,                angle DAB = angle ABC

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).